# merge 1 branch into another, but not all files/folders

Tags: git, merge, branching-and-merging, ignore

i want to merge my dev-branch into my master, but have some test-files/folders i don't want to merge.
I could make a "in between"-branch and remove these files/folders manually, but i hope for an better solution to make this faster/easier.

Is there any option to have something similar to git-ignore or any other solution, that it always don't merge these files/folders?

Comment: If you really want to do this, you will need to do it manually (though you can, e.g., `git merge --no-commit` followed by manual tweaks). Note that Git will assume that the merge result, whatever it is and however you build it, is the *correct* result of merging that history; future merges will use that correct result as input, and hence will omit—which, by comparison with earlier commits, means **delete** —those files.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume, You need to merge just file `**file1**` of branch **dev** into file f of branch **master**.
if I assume that all changes are committed in both branches dev and master. Then use these command.

> git checkout master
>
> git checkout --patch dev file1

The first command switches into branch master, into where you want to merge dev's version of the file1. The second command patches the file1 with file1 of HEAD of dev. You may even accept/discard single parts of the patch. Instead of dev you can specify any commit here, it does not have to be HEAD.

Now you may ask me:

> This only works if you want to update a file. What if I want to add a
> new file from branch dev to branch master?

Then my answer is

> You should be able to add a new file from B to A by removing the
> `--patch` option.